# TypeError: Cannot read property'map' of undefined, I want to implement select option using map, but there is a problem

Tags: reactjs

error code :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
PatientInfoModal
D:/test/pages/patient/PatientInfoModal.js:164
  161 |                </Form.Item>
  162 | 
  163 |                <Form.Item name={['patient', 'hospital']} label="Hospital" rules={[{ required: 
                                        true }]}>
> 164 |                     <Select placeholder="Select a Hospital" style={{ width:'150px' }}>
      | ^  165 |                     {testplz.map(a => <Option>{a.name}</Option>)}
  166 |                    </Select>
  167 |                </Form.Item>
```

mycode.js :

```
  const doctorplz = { doctor }
  const [ whats, whatsdata ] = useState("doctor")
  const testplz = doctorplz[whats]

  <Select placeholder="Select a Hospital" style={{ width:'150px' }}>
  {testplz.map(a => <Option>{a.name}</Option>)}
  </Select>
```

`console.log(doctorplz)` :

```
{doctor: Array(4)}
doctor: Array(4)
0: {d_code: 1, name: "test1", position: "RB", code_id: 1}
1: {d_code: 2, name: "test2", position: "LB", code_id: 2}
2: {d_code: 3, name: "test3", position: "ST", code_id: 2}
3: {d_code: 4, name: "test4", position: "RW", code_id: 1}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

I got the error despite entering the code correctly.
I don't know what the hell is wrong.

Also, the code below works fine.

mycode2.js (Code that works)

```
const namelist = {
    "01": [
      { d_code: '1', name: 'test1' },
      { d_code: '2', name: 'test2' },
      { d_code: '3', name: 'test3' }
    ]
  }

const [ data, setData ] = useState("01");
const Options = namelist[data];

<Select placeholder="Select a Doctor" style={{ width:'150px' }} >
{Options.map(a => <Option>{a.d_code}</Option>)}
</Select>
```

`console.log(namelist)` :

```
{01: Array(3)}
01: Array(3)
0: {d_code: "1", name: "test1"}
1: {d_code: "2", name: "test2"}
2: {d_code: "3", name: "test3"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

The format of the two data matches perfectly when running console.log().

But I don't know why I am getting the map error. Anything wrong with this code?

add `console.log(doctor)`:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {d_code: 1, name: "test1", position: "RB", code_id: 1}
1: {d_code: 2, name: "test2", position: "LB", code_id: 2}
2: {d_code: 3, name: "test3", position: "ST", code_id: 2}
3: {d_code: 4, name: "test4", position: "RW", code_id: 1}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: In the second example your `nameList` data is defined. What is `doctor` in the first snippet? If `doctorplz['doctor']` is undefined (or *not* defined *yet*) then you could see the error you have.

Comment: Console.log(doctor) was added to the post.

Comment: Yes, but what is `doctor` initially? How is it instantiated? When is it console logged? We need more context over the life of the component you are trying to render and the data it uses to better understand why it is undefined when you think it shouldn't.

Comment: It was solved thanks to the person who just posted the answer. I don't know why the answer is gone. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, using null checks can protect against undefined accesses, but don't generally get to the bottom of why data is unexpectedly undefined to begin with. I.E. it treats a symptom, but not the cause. I suspect you are loading `doctor` on component mount and it is simply undefined in the first initial render.  Either way, good luck.

Comment: @codeBeginner I added the answer back, I was looking at your code in detail and the flow is correct.

Comment: @Drew Reese I load it for the first time in componentDidMount. Is it a problem?

Comment: Potentially. If fetching/loading and saving it in state (i.e. something like `this.setState({ doctor })`) then it will become available in the *next* render cycle and `this.state.doctor` will remain undefined during the initial render. I guess it depends on what you mean by "load it" and what is done with it.

Comment: @Drew Reese Thank you very much. You developed me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testplz` might be initially empty, try adding a validation

```
 {testplz && Array.isArray(testplz) && testplz.map(a => <Option>{a.name}</Option>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are getting the doctor field as a props. If so, there is a chance that it might be undefined. In this case, undefined.map() will give error. So you can perform a simple check and then use map function

```
{ testplz ? 
           testplz.map( (data, index) => <Option key={index}>{data.name}</Option>:<p>Loading...<p>}
```